# Very High latency when running node.js + socket.io locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, socket.io, latency

Trying to implement a simple latency check, but I'm not sure if I'm getting it right.

`socket.emit('ping');` gets called every 2 seconds in the client side but the server never responds to it before the next call (see screenshot below).

In the same screenshot we can see that `pong` was only received 24 seconds later (12x) after the first `ping` call. It says `1094` which is in relation the last `ping` call but it's still VERY high.

What am I missing?

**client.js**

```
function start(){

    //starts connection
    socket = io();


    //Get socketID
    socket.on('socketID', function(data) {
        console.log('socketID: ' + socket.id);
    });


    //Start Measure latency

    setInterval(function() {
        startTime = Date.now();
        console.log('ping: ' + startTime);
        socket.emit('ping');
    }, 2000);

    socket.on('pong', function() {
        latency = Date.now() - startTime;
        console.log('pong ' + latency);
    });

    //end latency

}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server,{});

server.listen(8081, function(){
    console.log("Server is now running...")
});


app.get("/", function(req, res){
    //res.send("It works!");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use(express.static('client'));


//start server logic

//on connect
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.emit('socketID', {id: socket.id});
    console.log('New player connected: ' + socket.id);


    socket.on('ping', function() {
            socket.emit('pong');
        });

});
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: check your virus checker / internet security. nod32 was a pain in the ass for me with websockets; it would take ages of retrying to force through. Changing to pre-release (internet security) fixed it for me; disabling it entire too :)

Comment: Looks like a good direction now ;) .... I'm using mac and the only anti-virus I had was Avast which I just uninstalled but it's still very slow to respond. What do you mean by "pre-release (internet security)"?

Comment: nod32 has a pre-release branch to update from; it appeared there was a big in its firewall that delayed the websocket http requests. :/